# XPath search for all text nodes, not the inner text of any other child node

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack.

I hover over the parent node and its ChildNodes show several `#text` nodes.  The XPath value shows `/code[1]/#text[1]`.  I try to use `//#text` to get all the text nodes but I get that error:

Error: `Expression must evaluate to a node-set.`

I've tried `//text` and get nothing, but no error.

Comment: What is showing `/code[1]/#text[1]` as the XPath? That is not valid XPath.

Comment: @LarsH In the current HtmlNode (name=code)'s ChildNodes, opening up the first #text node and scroll down to it's XPath in the VS 2008 debugger, it shows that XPath.

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with the VS 2008 debugger, but the "XPath" it's showing you is not really XPath. :-( `#` is not part of the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `text()` to get text nodes.  To get all text nodes in the document, use `//text()`.

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-matching-item):

> `text()` matches any text node.

Comment: This works sort of.  I have the parent node and I do parent.SelectNodes("//text()") and I get all the text nodes for the parent, but also all the other text nodes below the parent in the document - strange!  I had to do parent.SelectNodes(parent.XPath + "//text()") to get all the texts, but wouldn't this still give the texts of children like style's etc?.

Comment: Have a go with `parent.SelectNodes("text()")`. I don't understand the last part of your question...

Comment: @Chuck, the fact that you are getting all text nodes that are descendants of the parent is exactly what `//` is for. `//` is the abbreviation for `descendant::`. If you just want text nodes that are direct children of `parent`, use `child::text()`. The abbreviation for that is just `text()`, as @lonesome suggested.

Comment: @LarsH Thanks, it is the child::text() that is the answer to my question.  If you could move /copy this comment as an answer I'll check it.

Comment: @Chuck, go ahead and accept @lonesome's answer... his `parent.SelectNodes("text()")` suggestion is equivalent to `parent.SelectNodes("child::text()")` and is what one would normally use.